# How to have bash shell not execute rest of semicolon list of commands?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Suppose you do following in bash at command prompt:

```
cmd1;cmd2;cmd3
```

If `cmd1` fails how do you get bash not to do `cmd2`.

Answer (score 8):

```
cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3
```

**Explanation**

Execute `cmd1`. If it fails, `cmd2` and `cmd3` will not be executed.

Why? Because *false* logically ANDed with anything else is always equal to *false*, so if `cmd1` returns *false* there is no need to evaluate `cmd2` and `cmd3`. And by like reasoning, if `cmd1` succeeds and `cmd2` fails, don't execute `cmd3`.

**Note**

Just to make things a little more confusing, POSIX systems (like Linux and other UNIX variants) return 0 for *success* and non-zero for *failure*.

So, when I say *failure* above

- **false** = **non-zero** = **failure**
- **true** = **zero** = **success**

Why? Because the numerical value of the return code is used indicate different failure codes.

For example,

```
$ ls /root
ls: cannot open directory /root: Permission denied
$ echo $? 
2
$ asdf
asdf: command not found...
$ echo $?
127
$ ls /
bin  boot  data  dev  etc  home  lib  ...
$ echo $?
0
```

`ls` returns "1" for minor problems and "2" for more serious problems. The bash shell returns "127" to indicate "command not found", and `ls /` returns "0" to indicate *success*.

Comment: @user1080552 To give a little explanation of why this works, "&&" is 'logical or', which short-circuits. That is, it evaluates from left-to-right, and once it evaluates any of the parts to false, it knows the entire result will be false, so it stops.

Comment: In addition to `&&`, there is also `||` - `cmd1 || cmd2` runs `cmd2` if `cmd1` fails.

Comment: @jam you meant "logical and".

Comment: @Maxime Thanks for catching that, but I can't edit the comment now D: